# Is it possible to change jquery mobile form elements , increase sizes by JS in %

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to resize jquery mobile form elements that I am using Phonegap in mobile App. Now I want to resize and give more height to form elements based on some number or percentage which will depend upon screen size. I know jquery Mobile handle width by itself but I want to give height via JS so that all form elements' height increase by that specific ratio/percentage.

I know that JQuery Mobile CSS can be changed but I want to change height using JS on runtime not setting CSS once. So what is best way to do this?

I actually want to get screen size and give size to all elements according to some percentage. While if I see at jQuery Mobile CSS then there are a lot of thing that I need to set, and still not sure if it will be set. So is there some way to do that without modifying or rewrite whole CSS? Or I just need to write custom CSS and form elements ?

Any suggestion and effort will be appreciated.

Comment: Each form element is rendered / enhanced by jQM in a different way. You'll eventually need to go through each element and do changes dynamically using `.css()`. For example, a text input is wrapped in a div.ui-input-text, and selectmenu is also wrapped in a div.ui-select. Hence, you first need to know the structure of all rendered DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle demonstrating this with input elements: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/akgEa/

In this example I have 3 inputs of type text and a button which doubles their height each time you click it. The button iterates through each input, gets its current height and then sets the height to 2 times current.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="textinput-fc1">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textinput-fc1" id="textinput-fc1" placeholder="Text input" value="" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="textinput-fc2">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textinput-fc2" id="textinput-fc2" placeholder="Text input" value="" />
</div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="textinput-fc3">Text Input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textinput-fc3" id="textinput-fc3" placeholder="Text input" value="" />
</div>

<input id="btnSet" type="button" value="Set Heights" data-theme="a" />

$('#btnSet').on("click", function(e){
    $("[type='text']").each(function( index ) {
        var curH = $(this).height();
        $(this).height(curH * 2);
    });
});
```

NOTE: depending what type of form elements you are using, setting height will not work for all of them. I suggest you look in the inspector at the generated code for your form and see what is the best way o set the height for each element type.

Comment: In your example, it just increase height of field but place where text is being displayed and text is still small. That points towards the same thing that I will need to increase height of many things for each element. So seems like there is no easy way to do this like, increase vertical size of whole form or all elements e.t.c.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there will be an easy one line of code that will automatically scale all elements of a form.

Comment: yah, I have done that now by updating fonts in form elements from its CSS, then change width of labels and input tags e.t.c. to fit width wise on screen. And it seems good.